# Как вручную проставить точку в числе?

Tags: java

Есть 10000 копеек, которые нужно привести к виду 100.00 рублей. С учётом того, что в рубле 100 копеек, можно вручную от конца числа отступать на 2 цифры, и если при шаге пусто, то заполнять нулями. Можно, но как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

как-то так в лоб:

```
void printRuble(int sum) {
    int kop = sum % 100;
    int rub = sum / 100;
    String format = String.format("%d.%02d", rub, kop);
    System.out.println(format);
}
```

результат: https://ideone.com/8WOi9I

Comment: спасибо, то что нужно

Answer (score 1):

Использовать `float`. Для вывода использовать `System.out.printf("%.2f", value);`, где `value` - это `float` того, что получилось при переводе в 100 рублей.

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        int ruble = 2546;
        double value = (double) ruble / 100;
        System.out.printf("%.2f", value);
     }
}
```

Вопрос до конца не понял. Если то - напиши в комментарии поточнее требования

Comment: float использовать нельзя. сумма должна быть в копейках типа int, поскольку все расчёты происходят в копейках, а на выходе уже нужны рубли с копейками в виде 2х цифр после запятой...  
т.е. если в результате расчётов программа получает 2456 (типа int) копеек, то на выходе нужно привести  к виду 24.56 рублей.

Comment: @Артур 2мин. сейчас напишу

Comment: @Артур поправил код. Так теперь можно?)

Comment: так надо поправить `int kop = 2546; double rub = kop / 100;` что бы всем стало сразу ясно где копейки и где рубли. а у вас всё шиворот-навыворот

Comment: спасибо) отличный ответ, просто я невнятно объяснил чего надо =)

Answer (score 0):

Если копейки - это поле в классе, то можно добавить простое свойство только для чтения для извлечения значения в рублях.

```
public class MyClass {
    private int kop;

    public int getKop() {
        return kop;
    }

    public void setKop(int kop) {
        this.kop = kop;
    }

    public double getRub() {
        return kop / 100;
    }
}

...

MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.setKop(10000);
System.out.printf("rub = %.2f", myClass.getRub());
```